# How to assign records of a table to a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables `vehicles` and `markers` . I took the id `veh_id` of table `vehicles` as a foreign key into `markers` table . I have only two records in `vehicles` table .
I want to assign 30 records of `markers` table to `veh_id`.

I have tried alot but didn't got success. 
Thanks

Comment: `UPDATE marker WHERE veh_id = mrk_id=1 to 30 `
Its not working :(

Comment: @shafee , are  there any records in your markers table ? i am not getting what are you trying to do , can you explain little more  :)

Comment: yeah i have 178 records in the table .
simply i want to assign 30 records to the foreign key .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following line in your Create table or update table query for marker table

```
CONSTRAINT foreign_vehid FOREIGN KEY(veh_id) REFERENCES vehicles(veh_id);
```

For this to work; both the fields(veh_id) should have common datatype.

If you want to set default value/null the here is a syntax:

```
[CONSTRAINT c_name]
[[FOREIGN KEY] ({col_name1} ,...)]
REFERENCES table_name ({col_name2},...)
[ON DELETE {NO ACTION| CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT}]
[ON UPDATE {NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Avidan
But what i want to assign the 30 records of markers table to a foreign key `veh_id`.

Comment: yeah its possible 
But ididn't got  your query logic .

Comment: i have created the foreign key now how to assign the value .

Comment: what is default value of foreign key in your marker table?

Comment: Default value is  `NULL`

Comment: `update market set veh_id = your_value where veh_id is null`

Just check whether it works.

Comment: Coool..!! Congrats..!!